# Import error in flask

Tags: python, flask, import

I am tryign to import create_app from app/**init**.py into conftest.py but I receive the following import error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'app'
```

My directory structure is like this:

```
root
 - app
    __init__.py
 - tests
    conftest.py
```

Here is my import code:

```
import pytest

from app import create_app
```

Comment: Can you show your import code?

Comment: Oh sorry, just added

Answer (score 0):

Just realised the tests folder was missing an **init**.py (albeit empty). It works after I add that in.